# How can I "unsplit" (ie reconnect) vertices that I split (not separated) from mesh in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

[image]Hopefully I can upload this video to show what I mean.
I add a cube, go into edit mode, extrude a bit. Use Y to split some of the mesh.
Move the split part away a bit. Then move the split part back.
Now I want to reconnect the split part to the main mesh.

So here I am not talking about two objects at all. It's all one object.
I am not talking about separating part of the mesh to new object.
I do not refer here to merging vertices either.
I mean the opposite of splitting. And I do not mean joining two objects.

Maybe there is a simple way I am overlooking.
Maybe Face> Intersect (Boolean)> Union?
Maybe Edge Loops added in exactly the right places, then merge by distance?

Here's where I'm asking if there's an easy way to sort of
"unsplit" some vertices that I had previously split (Y) from a mesh
while in edit mode.

Thanks for any ideas.

Note:I could not find a way to upload a nice little video to show what I mean, so here's at least a picture.

Edit_1:

Thanks for you ideas. In a bit more complex situation with the mesh, as this gif shows, how would one reconnect, or merge these two "unlinked" ? "islands" ? of vetices? Note that L selects linked vertices, so here I have some "unlinked" vertices. so my question is, how to get them back linked together so that L will select them all? Thanks for any other ideas to try. This is my first attempt to make and upload a gif to show what I mean.

[image: gif_1]

Comment: Merging IS the opposite of splitting so I am not sure what else you'd like to achieve. Unless, just have the bottom vertices of the top cube go at the same place as the top vertices of the bottom cube in which case you can use vertex snapping (little magnet in the tool bar)

Comment: Just in general, is there a way to link vertices that had been split with Y? And I mean in a more complex batch of vertices that would be very tedious to do all by hand with by using merge. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately I don't think vertices keep track and allow "undo" type operations individually...

Comment: Good point. So I'll go with there's no way to really efficiently relink a complex many vertices split "island". So in this type of situation maybe the closest thing to what I want is edit mode Boolean intersect> Union perhaps. Just wondering. Thanks again for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the arrangement of vertices, you may be able to use Grid Fill for something similar to this.  It won't remember which vertices were previously split from others, but it can be used to join two surfaces together.

[image: Grid Fill demo]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it way too much. If you only want the shape that you uploaded a picture of, it can be done in just 2 steps:

1: Inset the top face of the cube by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

2: Extrude the inset face up by pressing <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want that particular resulting form, I just am wondering if I am overlooking a simple way to reconnect parts of a mesh that I had previously split.